# Best class to represent a time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, f#

I'm working on timetabling application and I have a class:
called `ClassOption` representing a possible time to have a class.
with fields(/properties): `Day`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, and `Weeks`.

Now `Day` is easy it's type is `DayOfWeek`

`Weeks` is going to require me to make a custom class because it is represented by the universities own in-semester weeks notation or in a calendar week, but basically will come down to a set of integers, eventually.

But what calls should I use for `StartTime` and `EndTime`.
They are a time, but without any Date information.
`DateTime` seems like a reasonable choice, but they could be on any date. (/many dates)
By business logic they are both on the hour, but that doesn't really matter

Comment: The built in types for date handling are only fit for simple jobs IMO. Since your requirements are more complex, you might want to look into third party libraries, such as "Noda Time". I'm sure Jon will soon post an answer promoting Noda :P Edit: By "soon" I mean, "already did"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're happy to use a third party library which isn't quite at v1 yet, I'd like to plug [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com). You'd use the [`LocalTime`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/AllMembers_T_NodaTime_LocalTime.htm) struct.

If you're stuck with the base class library, you *might* want to use `TimeSpan`, or you could stick with `DateTime`. Obviously I think that `LocalTime` would be a more elegant solution though :)

Oh, and if you do use Noda Time, please let us know if you have any feature requests or comments...

Comment: Just as I saw that someone had posted. I thought: "Hey, wasn't Jon Skeet working on a Time library.". And Lo and Behold, here it is.

Comment: The `Duration` struct is a bit strange IMO. It seems completely redundant with `TimeSpan`. And I don't get your variable length field argument either. A second is always a second. That argument only applies to longer period-types, such as months and years. (days being a bit of a gray area). For some reason it also only supports integral values in it's `FromXYZ` functions.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, Duration is effectively equivalent to TimeSpan, but allows us to keep everything "within Noda" - supporting a consistent API (hopefully). And yes, *some* period fields have a fixed length, but others don't. Only supporting integral values for the FromXYZ functions seems reasonable to me - I've only ever wanted to specify fractional values when *really* I know the amount in a smaller unit, as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **DateDiff** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) to represent a time period:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void DateDiffSample()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime( 2009, 11, 8, 7, 13, 59 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date1: {0}", date1 );
  // > Date1: 08.11.2009 07:13:59
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20, 19, 55, 28 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date2: {0}", date2 );
  // > Date2: 20.03.2011 19:55:28

  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( date1, date2 );

  // description
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(1): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 1 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(1): 1 Year
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(2): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 2 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(2): 1 Year 4 Months
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(3): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 3 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(3): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(4): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 4 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(4): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(5): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 5 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(5): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours 41 Mins
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(6): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 6 ) );
  // > DateDiff.GetDescription(6): 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours 41 Mins 29 Secs
} // DateDiffSample
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use either DateTime, which can be used with time values only while ignoring the date, or with a TimeSpan, which can represent the time elapsed since midnight, and thus a time of day. In fact, that's exactly how it's used in a DateTime object, when you ask for the TimeOfDay, you get a TimeSpan.

Both are good in that they give you a set of convenient arithmetic operations to compare, add and subtract times. Just ignore the Date portion.

Comment: Adding and subtracting time can lead to problems with `DateTime` if you work on local times. DST is evil.